How to include unordered list inside a Quarto - Huxtable cell for Docx output?
I am trying to produce tables in which some cells contain unordered lists. I am trying to output to docx.
I tried the regular qmd tables, and flextable, and now I am in Huxtable.
The reason I chose to stick with Huxtable is because it provides better formatting options for my needs.
The one thing I am stuck on, which produces the error at the end of this post, is when I try to do bulleted lists inside a cell. Even when trying to use markdown, its failing to produce bulleted lists.
I tried different methods over the week and honestly I don't know what to do.
The code bit that is causing the issue: information[2, 1] <- "- test 1 \n - test 2 \n - test 3"
If anyone can kindly suggest other workarounds for in-cell bullets, or a solution, I would be really grateful.
Code to produce the error:
---
format: 
  docx: default
---


<!-- Information -->
```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false

library(huxtable)
library(officer)
library(systemfonts)

information <- hux(
    columnone = c("", ""),
    add_colnames = FALSE
)
information[1, 1] <- "test"
information[2, 1] <- "- test 1 \n - test 2 \n - test 3"


set_markdown(information)
```

And this error happens:
processing file: test.qmd
1/2
2/2 [unnamed-chunk-1]
Error in dplyr::bind_rows(.) : 
  Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
Calls: .main ... withRestartList -> withOneRestart -> docall -> do.call -> fun



Quitting from lines 9-26 [unnamed-chunk-1] (test.qmd)
Execution halted

The desired output: A cell with proper bullet points that are formatted as actual bullet points in word.
(I am using vscode + quarto extension to render)

You need to set markdown for the intended cell, and cross your fingers, as there are some features that are not supported, particularly paragraph-level properties: https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/reference/markdown.html
